# Scheduling an operation (NSTimer?)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image, scheduled-tasks, scheduling

I save some images locally. The user can associates/dissociates them to some text.
I would to check if an image is associated to a note and, if not, delete it from the local dir.
Should it better to check this every time the user dissociates the image?
or by scheduling the check?
In the second case, what could I use?

Comment: First question is not a programming question, it's more a usability/design aspect of your app. IMHO you should think hard about that before thinking about technical solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an `NSTimer` repeatable instance.

```
NSTimer* myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 60.0 target: self
                                       selector: @selector(callAfterSixtySecond:) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];
```

After each 60.0 second , iOS will call the below function

```
-(void) callAfterSixtySecond:(NSTimer*) t 
{
    NSLog(@"Check your image here ");
}
```